# How do I refresh a "form element" when it is changed through a webbrowser control?

Tags: vb6, browser, controls, dhtml

I am using VB6 (yes, I know it's 10 years old :), but it works). VB.NET answers may work as well, so if you know the answer, please answer too!

I am "manually" setting a dropdown box in a form, yet the 'webbrowser' doesn't seem to update.

[Here's an example](http://www.hgtv.com/hgtv-urban-oasis-2011-giveaway-enter/package/index.html)

If you notice in the form, it has a place where it asks you to fill in a state. (I.e., california, etc). It looks like a javascript/DHTML popup box in MSIE (firefox doesn't do the same, so you need to use MSIE, since that is what the webbrowser control relies on). If I 'click' on the "state" field, a popup box appears. I then can say select "CA" for california, and it updates it. (It now says "CA").

If I *progrmatically* do it, I would do something like:

```
WebBrowser1.forms(2).elements(13).value = "CA" ' (sets it to 'california')
WebBrowser1.forms(2).elements(13).item(9).selected = true (makes sure it is 'selected')
```

However -- within the webbrowser control -- it *still* appears as if nothing has changed. (In reality it has, i.e., if I submit the form it will submit the correct info), but it just doesn't "update" it.

Do you have any idea how I can do a "forced" refresh (either progrmatically or through some javascript/dhtml refresh), that will correctly then 'update' the field to show that "CA" has been selected?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The last VB version I used was VB3 so forgive my VB grammar :)

If the change event has a handler that you want to simulate

WebBrowser1.forms(2).elements(13).item(9).fireEvent ("onchange",WebBrowser1.Document.createEventObject())

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the response, I wasn't sure if I would get one because of the uniqueness of this question...

Ok... I tried that (for this specific webpage example), and it doesn't seem to "quite" work (I admit I didn't know about the fireevent property and/or how to use it). But anyways -- I've done that, and nothing seems to happen.

The equivalent code I am using (for the fireevent, which works without errors) is this:

WebBrowser1.forms(2).elements(13).value= "CA" WebBrowser1.forms(2).elements(13).fireEvent ("onchange",WebBrowser1.Document.createEventObject())

Comment: Do you know what I need to do for this specific example (the link above/example) to get the 'state' property to update? Thanks very much!

Comment: No... it looks like the select does not have an onchange handler, and setting the selected property should work, if you found the item correctly. There is an example at http://www.daftlogic.com/information-programmatically-preselect-dropdown-using-javascript.htm that you can use as a reference